# scheduled emails with attachement

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

to send scheduled emails with attachement  from odoo 8

```
self.env['mail.message'].schedule_with_attach(cr, uid, email_from.value or '', [email_to], email_subject, report_body, model=model,subtype='html')
```

I use it for odoo 10 but 'mail.message' has no attribute 'schedule_with_attach'

how can I use shedule email with attachement for odoo 10